# TFS 2010 unexpected output - merge Dev to Gold

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, merge

A compare is run on server versions of source branch Dev to Target Branch Gold. No other pending changes exist for the team project aside 5 Files which differ between the 2 branches.  A merge is performed from Dev to Gold, 1 conflict exists on a *.cs file, the change is saved with the merge tool.

When attempting to check in the changes on the gold branch following the merge, every single file within the Gold Branch has a pending merge, lock.  Expected changes are the 5 files which differ.  What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen when you are merging a renamed branch or doing baseless merge.

Comment: Can you tell me why this might need to occur for a renamed branch?

Comment: Behind the scenes, branch rename is actually branch + delete (new one is branched from the old, then the old is deleted). When you try to merge the renamed branch, TFS will perform a baseless merge which makes it to appear as all files in the branch have changed even though they haven't changed.